# algorithm for placing objects freely on a screen

Tags: algorithm

with my application I have different objects (for simplicity let's say all rectangles) that can be of different sized and located freely on screen (drag/drop).

The problem I have is that a user create the page on certain screen size but it gets viewed on different screen sizes. It's not a big deal if differences are small say 15" vs 14" laptops) but it looks quite messed up if created on say 27" mac and viewed on 14" laptop.

I tried storing screen dimensions and then resizing/relocating object relatively but didnt work that well.

Do you know of an algorithm to solve such a problem? if not do you recommend a method/idea of how I go about solving that?

Comment: I like your idea of relativ dimensions and positions. What didn't work well?

Comment: how exactly are you storing the page?

Comment: The first problem I can see with storing size relatively is that some content does not scale well, pictures notably (unless they are in a vectorized format). Otherwise I can't see why proportions would not work.

Comment: To answer some of the comments. I store x, y, width, height, rotation, screen_width and screen_height. It works it's just that the spacing between the objects so if you make something at a bigger screen and then view on smaller the distance between objects changes and that make look not that great, so text and photo look further apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing & relocating relatively sounds fine. The only problem is that a square drawn at 800x600 will not be a square on 1920x1200 unless you also compensate for screen ratio. Then if you start compensating for screen ratio to keep squares squared you get [letterboxing issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widescreen#Widescreen_computer_displays).